# Can 'artificial' be used alone?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

My dictionary defines ***artificial*** as *made or produced by human beings rather than occurring naturally, especially as a copy of something natural*.

But since any manufactured substance can only be created from something that has natural origins, can anything simply be described as ***artificial***?

Are we not restricted, in the use of the word ***artificial***, to placing it as an adjective, in front of nouns? We talk, for example, about ***artificial fibres***, meaning things like nylon, or polyester, which do not occur naturally as fibres as do wool or cotton. Similarly someone may have an ***artificial limb***.

But placing a notice on a food package saying ***nothing artificial contained here*** I would suggest is nonsense, since everything in the world is either extracted, manufactured, or contrived through chemical process from a naturally occurring substance of some sort.

Can ***artificial*** be used alone without further qualification?

Comment: I don't see a problem. I could take naturally occurring potatoes, mash them up and then reconstruct the mashed potato back into an *artificial* potato made entirely of naturally occurring potato. The term qualifies the object not its ingredients.

Comment: @MarvMills Which I think is the point I am making in my question. But last night I had a bag of potato crisps on which was written 'nothing artificial contained'. I don't see how it can make sense. Since in a broad scope nothing in the world can be 'artificial'.

Comment: Someone could point to my artificial but exceptionally skilfully made reconstituted potato and exclaim "Is that artificial?" to which I would answer "Yes, it is artificial".. No noun needed. In your example I would agree it is a nonsensical use of the term, but if the bag contained potatoes it would be correct. So the term has a valid use, but like anything, may be mis-used.

Comment: @MarvMills So the manufacturers were not being honest. Everything about the potato crisps was 'artificial'!

Comment: If you want to get really semantic, make some potato crisps out of mashed rice and add potato flavour. Are these "artificial potato crisps"? If the answer is "yes" does that make the originals "natural"? Is "natural" the only possible antonym of "artificial"?

Comment: @MarvMills Seems like 'artificial' is a gradable adjective, and that there are degrees of artificiality.

Comment: I'm personally not convinced there are degrees of artificiality, more that the antonym of "artificial" can also be "authentic" or "genuine", which still keeps the binary meaning. +1 Interesting question.

Comment: What difference does choosing a particular noun make? What's wrong with a picture of the sun labelled 'nothing artificial contained here'?

Comment: @Marv Mills  
'I'm personally not convinced there are degrees of artificiality'. This surely overlaps with the debate on the term 'organic' (foodstuffs etc domain). What if man has intervened in a natural process to some degree? Think of the cline GM ... chemical weedkillers ... selective breeding ... crop rotation ... weeding ... ploughing etc for a field crop. The terms are variously defined and understood.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Which was sort of the point I was making from the start!

Comment: I thought you were asking the question: 'Can _artificial_ be used alone without further qualification?' I mustn't have got the hang of this site yet.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I totally agree, furthermore I believe that it has now been proven that foodstuffs bearing the appellation "organic" are no better than non-organic foodstuffs (though I cannot remember the definition of *better*) in that proof and I don't have a ready citation.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This started with a question I asked last night, which got closed. I was eating a bag of Kettle Chips on which the words 'nothing artificial contained here' was printed. I am claiming it a nonsense, since if you take 'artificial' in a strict sense, the crisps themselves are artificial. In a broader sense nothing can be artificial anyway. So the only meaningful way to use the term is as an adjective qualifying a noun, such as 'artificial fibre'. Nylon and polyester one can definitely say are 'artificial fibres', though broadly they cannot, by definition be 'artificial'.

Comment: [Here's another facet, courtesy of ITV](http://www.itv.com/news/wales/2014-04-28/semi-artificial-pitch-given-go-ahead-at-millennium-stadium/): Semi-artificial pitch given go-ahead at Millennium Stadium The Welsh RU has [OK'd] plans to install a £3.3m semi-artificial pitch at the Millennium Stadium, five months on from outlining it was the preferred option they were considering.

The so-called 'desso' surface ... has become the norm at top level grounds throughout Britain ... Made up of artificial fibres weaved in between a majority of natural grass strands ... [hopefully] far stronger.

Comment: Ah well, you see, that's commercial TV combined with sports, normal rules do not apply/are a game of two halves...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In strict terms what they mean is 'artificial grass'. That is a just and proper use of the term. As I understand it all top sports grounds (Premier League etc) have grass that is part artificial, these days.

Comment: The situation with usages of 'artificial' is more complex than a matter of a few broad-brush attempts made by dictionaries to nail down the sum total of senses. As someone has said, "[W]e don't call steel 'artificial wood' just because it has replaced wood as a construction material (for ships and building etc)." Dictionary definitions rarely warn one of the idiosyncracies in usage rendering some perfectly plausible framings non-idiomatic.

Comment: Are you essentially asking  "Is 'artificial' a noun or an adjective?"? That is "There is nothing distasteful contained here." seems wrong to you?

Comment: @Mitch I'm not quite sure of the point you are making by including 'distasteful'. Clearly, it, and 'artificial' are  both adjectives.

Comment: @WS2: My point is that, as an adjective, 'distasteful' can stand alone. 'No distasteful ingredients', 'Those ingredients are distasteful'. Same with 'natural'. Same with 'artificial'. Is that your question, whether it's grammatical for any of these adjectives to stand alone like that? 'It is red', 'It is distasteful', 'It is artificial'

Comment: @Mitch The fact of 'artificial' being an adjective does not necessarily mean it can stand alone, like many other adjectives can. How about: *different, designated, assorted, accumulated, distinct* etc?

Comment: @WS2 syntax-wise most adjectives (like all the ones you mention) can stand alone. Not all adjective things can. That's what distinguish articles and possessive pronouns ('our' can't but 'ours' can), motivating categorizing these slightly differently from adjectives. But all the ones you mention _can_ stand alone.

Comment: @Mitch I would agree with you that syntax-wise they can perfectly stand alone. But my point is that they need to qualify something specific. What would 'Is there anything designated in that box'? mean. If all parties to the conversation knew what it was that you were 'designating', that would be fine; but as a remark out of the blue it would be meaningless. Just as 'there is nothing artificial contained in these crisps' is meaningless.

Answer (score 7):

You mentioned food products as an example. 'No artificial ingredients,' or 'all natural' come to mind.

These terms are unregulated by the FDA in America (only 'organic' has real meaning on packaging in these terms).

So in this sense, these words are meaningless when used in advertising or on packaging. I believe that answers part of your question.

The meaning, beyond that, is a matter of personal opinion. As such an ambiguous term, in conversations in which a shared understanding of artificiality is necessary, I recommend specifically pursuing a mutual understanding of what the word should mean for the purposes of that conversation.

Comment: 'Context is everything' as a contributor is fond of saying. I like 'all words are infinitely polysemous'.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it can be use a alone, but the exact meaning will depend on context and in some cases it may be ambiguous.

For example in British (and I expect European Union) food labelling law, an ingredient is considered artificial if it includes a chemical compound that was created other than in a living thing or natural process.

Comment: If the compound is identical to one from a living thing, it can be called "nature identical", but not "natural".

Comment: I don't know anything about food-labelling law. But I am fairly certain that British law, in this regard, follows EU regulation entirely.

Answer (score 3):

**"Nothing is created or destroyed, but merely transformed."**  who said that?

It is clear that anything comes from what we already have in nature.  Transformation (generally via chemical processes) is what characterises something from being natural or artificail The degree of transformation can give rise to debates to the fact that someting is closer to being natural or artificial, but still the concept holds.

*'Natural, organic, non-artificial'* are all catchwords which marketing strategies use and abuse....well beyond their literal meanings.

Comment: On that basis you could argue that the potato crisps were entirely 'artificial', since the potatoes have been harvested, sliced, treated with various other ingredients, had heat applied to them whilst placed in oil, and finally packed in a paper bag. On your definition that produces something quite artificial.

Comment: @WS2 - my grandfather used to grow vegetables, we used to eat them, they were 100% natural. We now live in an industrialized world and they try to convince us that the food that they produce is more natural than artificial (chemically treated). The extent to which this is true, we really can't tell.. but we tend to buy more 'natural, organic' food!! That's it!!

Comment: 'Organic food' is now popular among a lot of people in Britain, especially since Prince Charles went in for it in a big way. But the prices are staggering. We restrict ourselves to 'free range eggs'. The thought of high-density battery farming of hens makes me feel quite ill.

Comment: Antoine Lavoisier wrote that. (although he did not write it in english, and I would not find that traduction to be very accurate)

Answer (score 2):

"Nothing artificial contained here" can be read as "no artificial thing [is] contained here".  The word "artificial" acts as an adjective, modifying the pronoun "nothing".  True, it happens to follow the word that it modifies, but it still qualifies that word.

If you intended the question "Can artificial be used alone without further qualification?" to mean "Can the word 'artificial' be used as a noun?" then the answer is generally no.  Adjectives *can* be used as pronouns, but I doubt that that's the sort of use that interests you, and it's not a particularly common use for this adjective.

On the other hand, it can stand alone, for instance as a verb's argument.  It functions perfectly well as a predicate adjective, as in "These flowers are artificial."

In the acceptable examples that you gave -- artificial fibers and artificial limbs -- the nouns don't qualify this adjective.  Instead, this adjective qualifies the nouns.  That point seems to be at the heart of your confusion.

Comment: This.  Also consider *Nothing purple contained here*, which uses the same syntax, but makes the adjective clearer.